# Camera size in andengine for tablets

Tags: android, andengine

I'm writing a game specifically for Android tablets, using andengine. If I use fixed camera,
andengine  will scale the view to fill the device screen. What values I have to use for CAMERA_WIDTH and CAMERA_HEIGHT, so that the game will work fine on most popular tablets? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should consider writing for a particular size - say a 7" tablet - the Nexus 7 has a resolution of 1280 x 800. Then let AndEngine use a RatioResolutionPolicy to adjust for the differences in any other screen sizes.  See this answer for more info

[Sprite size on different screen size Andengine Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399045/sprite-size-on-different-screen-size-andengine-android/11412294#11412294)