# Curious about Camera Width and height in andEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I looked at many examples of andEngine Gles2.0 All of them take these :

```
private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
```

Why is this value fixed? Why can't I do this:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
int honeyComb = android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2;

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
if (currentapiVersion >= honeyComb) {
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    CAMERA_WIDTH = size.x;
    CAMERA_HEIGHT = size.y;
} else {
    CAMERA_WIDTH = display.getWidth();
    CAMERA_HEIGHT = display.getHeight();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that if you want to. I think the key though is to define a fixed size like 480x800 and write your game/app to that size making sure everything looks right at that one resolution. Then use a RatioResolutionPolicy and let AndEngine deal with scaling things to fit other screen sizes. See my answer to this question for more thoughts on this

[Sprite size on different screen size Andengine Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399045/sprite-size-on-different-screen-size-andengine-android/11412294#11412294)