# AndEngine, A big part of the screen is black

Tags: android, andengine

Hi EveryBody I'm following this AndEngine Game Tutorial http://www.matim-dev.com/, but I have problem with screen becouse is black in a part of it. This is my code to starts EngineOptions:

```
@Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Get Display Device Information 
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        this.camera = new Camera(0, 0, size.x, size.y);
        EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true,
                ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(
                        size.x, size.y), camera);
        engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(true).setNeedsSound(true);
        engineOptions.setWakeLockOptions(WakeLockOptions.SCREEN_ON);
        return engineOptions;
    }
```

Anybody know how to solves this problem?

Thank a lots!

Comment: In the following post we were discussing similar thing, so you look at this you definitely get something, http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50165/how-do-i-support-variable-screen-ratios-using-andengine

Comment: can you post that specific link...and rest of the functions like..createScene and onpopulate.

Answer (score 1):

you need use FillResolutionPolicy when charge the EngineOptions

```
 EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true,
            ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new FillResolutionPolicy(), camera);
```

This method autorezise to all devices

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed many times - see my answer to this post [Sprite size on different screen size Andengine Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399045/sprite-size-on-different-screen-size-andengine-android/)

You can't really completely remove the black bars though - at least not using a RatioResultionPolicy.