# Graphics gets stretch for small screen

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing an Android game using [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) which support all screen resolution (Large,medium & small screen). The camera width=720, camera height=480 and I am using all in-game Graphics according to this screen size(i.e 720x480).

I have a problem that when I install my game on small screen resolution devices, all my in-game Images(graphics) are getting stretched or shrink. I am loading all Image resources from assets folder**strong text**.

If I use Ratio Resolution Policy() then entire screen will not cover.
Is there any solution for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what ResolutionPolicy are you using? can you show us the code where you create the engine

Comment: public Engine onLoadEngine() {
         this.mCamera = new  Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

        return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new  FillResolutionPolicy(), this.mCamera).setNeedsMusic(true).setNeedsSound(true));
     }

Comment: have you tried it with a RatioResolutionPolicy? See this post for some insight - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399045/sprite-size-on-different-screen-size-andengine-android/11412294#11412294

Comment: yes i have tried this, but entire screen will not cover.

Comment: well, you basically have the 2 choices - RatioResolutionPolicy and possibly not filling the entire screen - or FillResolutionPolicy which will cover the screen but to do that it will have to stretch the graphics. You need to decide which is more important - filling the screening or not stretching the graphics. Even if you get it to work on your device(s), it's not going to be the same on every device - personally, I'd go with the RatioResolutionPolicy and live with the padding.

Comment: Thanks. now i got clear idea